# Obstacle Avoidance: Detection of goal inside the obstacle

Tags: mobile-robot, control

It is easy to understand how a robot can avoid obstacle if the goal point is not within the obstacle (Point A) as shown in the figure. But I'm curious how could a robot know that the the goal point is within the obstacle (Point B)? For example in an area exploration using random motion, the way-point is generated randomly. If the generated way-point located inside the obstacle, how could robot know? How to detect this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same obstacle detection and path planning approach that can get you from O to A should be able to also tell you that B is not reachable.

It will depend on the planning strategy for how this manifests. It should be able to say though that either every option has been exhausted (if that's finite and realistically achievable) or that it needs to give up after making a reasonable number of attempts. It may, therefore, not always be possible (or at least practical) to distinguish between B being fully inside an obstacle versus being surrounded by obstacles with only a very narrow opening between them.